# NPP graph cut for non-integer edge capacities

Tags: cuda, graph-theory, npp

The `nppiGraphcut_32s8u` function works on 32 bit signed integer edge capacities. In the grabCut example included with the CUDA 6.5 toolkit, they simply cast `Npp32f` to `Npp32s`. For example, from `GrabcutUtil.cu` in the grabcutNPP example folder:

```
// Top/Bottom
Npp32s bottom;
bottom = _FIXED(edge_weight(center, tex2D(imageTex, x + 0.5f ,y + 1.5f), alpha, beta, 1.0f));
```

where `edge_weight` returns a `Npp32f`.
Did they scale up their numbers so that the edge capacities would be large values and thus avoid rounding off error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a 'cast'. 
Look at the implementation: _FIXED first multiplies the number by 10 and then calls a rounding routine.

So yes, the number is scaled up, although only by one digit.